# What is the Probable Number of Occurrences when the Odds Change at a Set Rate over Time?

Tags: probability

Odd Saturday night question:

At time = 0s, the probability of an event is .25.

At time = 100s, the probability of an event is 1.

The probability increase is linear, so the equation for the probability as a function of time is .0075*t + .25

Each second a roll is made to see if there has been a success or not. Successes are noted, and time marches forward.

I would like to determine the probable number of successes between time 0 to 100s, but I can't figure out how to do so without calculating the odds for each event and doing some kind of an average of the sum. If that's even the right way to go.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Maybe, because the growth is linear, I could say that the average probability of success would be the average of the probability at time 100 and time 0? So, in this case .75/2?

If that's correct, then the number of success expected would be 101 * .75/2 = 37.875?

Or am I really off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ave probability is 1/2 (1 + 0.25) = .625

expected # successes is $101 \times 0.625.$

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that.